# Unable to write to stream error from Log4j

Tags: java, spring, log4j

Getting given below error while write the log into text file using Log4j.

```
    2019-07-19 00:05:20,234 ERROR Unable to write to stream /apps/logs/myapps.log for appender debug-log
    2019-07-19 00:05:20,235 ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender debug-log org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error flushing stream /apps/logs/myapps.log
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.flush(OutputStreamManager.java:159)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:112)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.append(RollingFileAppender.java:88)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:99)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:430)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:409)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:367)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:112)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:727)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:716)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.error(AbstractLogger.java:344)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Missing file or filesystem
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:342)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:151)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.flush(OutputStreamManager.java:156)
```

File already exists in location and I have clear the log file and have enough space in unix server ,even though i am facing this issue.

Refer the given below log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">/apps/logs/</Property>
        <Property name="app-name">Mytesting</Property>
        <Property name="machine-name">${hostName}</Property>        
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${app-name} ${machine-name} %p %c{2}.%M.%L %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="debug-log" fileName="myapps.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/myapps.log-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log"
            append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${app-name} ${machine-name} %p %c{2}.%M.%L %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>               
            </Policies>         
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all" additivity="false">
             <appender-ref ref="console-log" level="off"/>
             <appender-ref ref="debug-log" level="debug"/> 
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: And oddities? For example do you have rsyslog configured to rotate files? Are you running in docker?

Comment: This  is just jar application , and its called by one or more java process concurrently. ie one or more java instance  calling this application, this application writing the log into single log file  that is  /apps/logs/myapps.log

Comment: Ah - there you go; that's an oddity. They're writing to the same log file and rotating it out from underneath from eachother. You can't just have multiple applications log to the same file! Especially when you have each application configured for rotating said file...